# Exception Passing SAFEARRAY in VARIANT to C# From C++ COM Server

Tags: c#, c++, com, variant

I have spent the last day searching documentation, reviewing forum posts,  and googling to try to do something that I am guessing could be easily done with the right information.

I have a very large existing C++ application that has an already defined COM server with many methods exposed. I am trying to use those COM methods in a C# application (I am experienced in C++, but a C# newbie).

So in my VS2010 C# application, I add the COM server as a reference. COM Methods are visible in the object browser, and passing single-valued strings, floats, and ints seems to work fine.

But I am stumped trying to read SAFEARRAY values passed out of the C++ COM server into the C# application. Eventually I need to pass string arrays from C++ server to the C# app, but in just testing passing an array of floats, I have code that builds but fails with the following exception when I try to cast the System.Object containing the array of floats to (float[])  ,

"exception {System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Single[]'."

With intellisence I can see that the Object contains the correct 8760 long array of floats, but I am unable to access that data in C#.

Here is the code on the C# side (d2RuleSet is an interface defined in the DOE2Com COM server). The exception above is thrown on the last line below.

```
DOE2ComLib.DOE2Com d2RuleSet;

d2RuleSet = new DOE2ComLib.DOE2Com();

System.Int32 i_Series =0;

System.Object pv_WeatherData;
float[] faWeatherData;

iOut = d2RuleSet.GetWeatherData(i_Series, out pv_WeatherData);
Type typeTest;
typeTest = pv_WeatherData.GetType();
int iArrayRank = typeTest.GetArrayRank();
Type typeElement = typeTest.GetElementType();                    
faWeatherData = (float[])pv_WeatherData;
```

Below is the section in the idl file defining the C++ COM method

```
HRESULT GetWeatherData( [in] int iSeries, [out] VARIANT* pvWeatherData,    [out,retval]      int * piErrorCode);
```

Below is the C++ code where the VARIANT data is loaded.

```
void CDOE2BaseClass::GetWeatherData( int iSeries, VARIANT* pvWeatherData, int*   piErrorCode)
{
    *piErrorCode = 0;

    if (iSeries < 0 || iSeries >= D2CWS_NumSeries)
       *piErrorCode = 1;
    else if (m_faWeatherData[iSeries] == NULL)
       *piErrorCode = 3;
    else
   {
       SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsaBound;
       rgsaBound.lLbound = 0;
       rgsaBound.cElements = 8760;

      // First lets create the SafeArrays (populated with VARIANTS to ensure    compatibility with VB and Java)
       SAFEARRAY* pSAData = SafeArrayCreate( VT_VARIANT, 1, &rgsaBound );
       if( pSAData == NULL ) {
 #ifndef _DOE2LIB
          _com_issue_error( E_OUTOFMEMORY);
#else
//RW_TO_DO - Throw custom Lib-version exception
          OurThrowDOE2LibException(-1,__FILE__,__LINE__,0,"OUT OF MEMORY");
 #endif //_DOE2LIB
       }

      for (long hr=0; hr<8760; hr++)
      {
          COleVariant vHrResult( m_faWeatherData[iSeries][hr] );
          SafeArrayPutElement( pSAData, &hr, vHrResult );
       }

      // Now that we have populated the SAFEARRAY, assign it to the VARIANT pointer that we are returning to the client.
       V_VT( pvWeatherData ) = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
       V_ARRAY( pvWeatherData ) = pSAData;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help with this problem, I feel like I spent too much time on what should be a simple problem. Also please post up any links or books that that cover interop between native C++ and C# well (I think I have already ping-ponged through most of the Visual Studio/MSDN documentation, but maybe I missed something there too).

-----------------End Of Original Question------------------------------------------------------
I am editing to post the code from phoog's successful solution below, so others can read and use it.

```
int iOut = 0;
System.Int32 i_Series =0;
System.Object pv_WeatherData = null;

iOut = d2RuleSet.GetWeatherData(i_Series, out pv_WeatherData);
Type typeTest;
typeTest = pv_WeatherData.GetType();
int iArrayRank = typeTest.GetArrayRank();
Type typeElement = typeTest.GetElementType();

//float[] faWeatherData = (float[])pv_WeatherData;
float[] faWeatherData = ConvertTheArray((object[])pv_WeatherData);
```

....

```
float[] ConvertTheArray(object[] inputArray)
{
   float[] result = new float[inputArray.Length];
   for (var index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
      result[index] = (float)inputArray[index];
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data in `pv_WeatherData` is a IEEE single floating point and not, say, double? What happens if you cast it to `Object[]` or just `Array` and inspect it in the debugger? Oh, I just noticed that it is indeed an InvalidCastException. You've got the wrong type, and will need to cast.

Comment: what happen in the other case? e.g. if I have a C++ function to use in my C# app and the function is expecting to receive a matrix for example: MyUnmanagedFunction(&Array); How can I pass in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marshalled SAFEARRAY is a `System.Object[]`; you can't reference-convert that to a `System.Single[]`.  You have to cast the individual elements.  This would work, assuming that all the elements of the argument array are in fact boxed floats:

```
float[] ConvertTheArray(object[] inputArray)
{
    float[] result = new float[inputArray.Length];
    for (var index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
        result[index] = (float)inputArray[index];
    return result;
}
```

You could do that with a lot less typing using Linq, but as you're a C# newbie I thought a more basic solution might be better.

**EDIT**

Since you indicated in your comment that your `object[]` is referenced as an `object`, here's the usage example:

```
object obj = GetMarshalledArray();
float[] floats = ConvertTheArray((object[])obj);
```

**EDIT 2**

A shorter solution using Linq:

```
float[] ConvertTheArray(object[] inputArray)
{
    return inputArray.Cast<float>().ToArray();
}
```

Comment: phoog, thanks so much for the quick response. The problem is that pv_WeatherData is a single object rather than an array of objects, so I get a compile error when I try to pass it to ConvertTheArray. The pv_WeatherData object has System.Array type and intellisense shows the float when I hover the cursor over it. I have not done any custom marshalling, just referenced the type library for the COM server in my C# app.

Comment: ,I am confused about the type that pv_WeatherData represents. The exception I pasted in above says "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Single[]'".But the declaration of pv_WeatherData is System.Object. But when I hover over pv_WeatherData in the debugger before the exception the type of pv_WeatherData is object[].

Comment: @TommyVee if the object reference points to an object of type `System.Object[]`, as the exception message implies, then you can cast it `(object[])obj`.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, the cast and your function worked. Thanks so much, could you recommend a good book or website on C++ C# COM interop? I am in backwoods Costa Rica at the moment, but at least I could order it. I am going to edit my question with the working code, just so other users can see it and use it.

Comment: @TommyVee unfortunately I don't know of a good book; I'm not even particularly well versed in the topic myself.  I arrived at the solution purely from the C# side, using the information in the exception message that the returned object is an `object[]` array; the rest follows in the context of the C# type system.

Comment: @TommyVee I just did a little more research for another question and came up with this msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.100).aspx; if you haven't seen it already it should be helpful.  The basic principle (as you've no doubt realized) is that a SAFEARRAY is marshalled to a .NET array whose type depends on the SAFEARRAY's element type; if the SAFEARRAY elements are variants then the managed array is an `object[]`.  Also I added a Linq solution to my answer.